# C# Loading collection on viewModel

Tags: c#, linq

I have a viewmodel that has a header property, and then an associated child collection as such:

```
public int ProjectApprovalHeaderId { get; set; }

public List<ProjectApprovalStepsVM> ProjectApprovalHistorySteps{ get; set; }
```

I have a query that returns the data as follows:

```
ProjectApprovalHeaderId StepName Status
1                       Step1      A
1                       Step2      C
1                       Step3      A
2                       Step1      D
```

I'm trying to write the LINQ so that I can populate the viewmodel with the HeaderId and then the child collection with the actual step data but I'm stuck.  I know this isn't much, but it's where I'm at:

```
var approvalHistory = from s in _context.ProjectApprovalSteps
    join u1 in _context.Users on s.AssignedApproverID equals u1.ID
    join p in _context.Projects on s.ProjectID equals p.ID
    join sc in _context.ApprovalStepStatusCodes on s.Status equals sc.StatusCode into statusList
    from scd in statusList.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where s.ProjectID == projectId
    orderby s.ProjectApprovalHeaderID, s.Sequence
           select new ProjectApprovalHistoryVM
              {
              ProjectApprovalHeaderId = s.ProjectApprovalHeaderID,
              ProjectApprovalHistorySteps = 
              };

vmApprovalHistory.ProjectApprovalHistorySteps = approvalHistory.ToList();
```

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You need a `group by` - to group the records by `ProjectApprovalHeaderID` and then `select new ProjectApprovalHistoryVM { ProjectApprovalHeaderId = x.Key, ProjectApprovalHistorySteps = x.Select(y => new ProjectApprovalStepsVM{ StepName = y.StepName, Status = y.Status })`

Comment: Thank you Stephen, this got me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of Dapper, you can install via Nuget `Install-Package Dapper`.  The reason I recommend, is the multi mapping capabilities.  So an object like you have, has nested objects that are needed to be populated and filtered.

```
    public IEnumerable<SpeciesModel> GetAllSpecies() => dbConnection
        .Query<SpeciesModel, SpeciesCategoryModel, SpeciesTypeModel, WetlandIndicatorModel, SpeciesModel>(getAllSpeciesQuery,
            (species, speciesCategory, speciesType, wetlandIndicator) =>
            {
                species.SpeciesCategory = speciesCategory;
                species.SpeciesType = speciesType;
                species.WetlandIndicator = wetlandIndicator;
                return species;
            });
```

So the above syntax is expressing the nested object.  As your query is returned, it'll also associate your child objects.  I believe that is your intent, plus this saves you a lot of time.

More complex example with a collection as a nested object with Dapper.

```
    public IEnumerable<StemModel> GetStemModelForPlotHeader(int projectParameter, int plotParameter,
        string plantCommunityParameter) =>
        dbConnection.Query<StemModel, PlotSurveyModel, PlantCommunityModel, ProjectModel, SpeciesModel, StemModel>(getAllPlotHeaderDetails,
            (stem, survey, plantCommunity, project, species) =>
            {
                stem.PlotSurvey = survey;
                survey.PlantCommunity = plantCommunity;
                survey.Project = project;
                stem.Species = species;
                return stem;
            },
            new
            {
                ProjectId = projectParameter,
                PlantCommunityCode = plantCommunityParameter,
                PlotNumber = plotParameter
            });
```

**Update:**

---

Please note the above answer would require you to replace your data access layer.  I'm impartial to Dapper, since you receive the performance with the extra mapping functionality.  Especially for simple queries, but you can leverage the performance with extra mapping capabilities.  Also it forces your data calls to be SQL oriented, not code generating dynamic queries.

Comment: @AluanHaddad What API, that looks like LINQ to SQL to me?  Where does the OP mention an API?

Comment: yes and it (LINQ2SQL) does what you show how to write by hand in Dapper, so-called multi mapping, automatically by examining the database schema. Further refinement are trivially added with additional select clauses, but Dapper is a fundamentally lower level of abstraction and requires more code

Comment: @AluanHaddad Except Dapper does it way faster than LINQ to SQL, and uses a bunch of custom IL.  So not sure why a micro ORM would be invalid?  It faster, easier to read, and solves the issue?  If the OP said I have to do it with LINQ to SQL, then yes I understand my answer being invalid but he doesn't.

Comment: it's only relevant if you have a known well benchmarked and thoroughly researched bottleneck in your system. It is absolutely not easier to read, and it is much harder to maintain. Keep it simple. Let the tools work for you. If you find a place where you know you need to make it go faster than you could add Dapper

Comment: @AluanHaddad Isn't that subjective?  I mean I find SqlDataReader even easier and faster than Linq to SQL.  Especially since your letting SQL do its job, not using code to dynamically build queries.

Comment: well since he's using Linq to SQL in the first place, I see no reason for him to change. It's very effective. Don't forget that when you drop down to that layer you have to worry about a lot of other things as well. Also Dapper has some very poorly designed apis, `"splitOn"` is frankly embarrassing,  the behavior of `.OrWhere` is error prone, and the documentation is awful.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Well, the `splitOn` and `OrWhere` is pretty horrible, won't dispute that.  But still solves ninety percent of usage, I'm not a fan of Linq to SQL.  I tend to use SqlDataReader, Dapper, or EF.  I'd say we both have beneficial reasoning.

Comment: Agreed, I appreciate your diplomacy :)

Comment: I appreciate legitimate feedback, a lot of people down vote or don't offer to help the OP, or even people helping OP.  Appreciate speaking to other engineers with other view sets, different approaches to issues, helps us all grow.

Comment: Well said, sir. Maybe just add a note to this answer explaining that it involves swapping out the database layer that the OP is using.

Comment: Will do that after this meeting.